# Подсветка нового элемента в TableView

Tags: xcode, objective-c, ios, iphone

Как реализовать подсвечивание новых строк в TableView?
Например, как в комментариях ВКонтакте

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Незнаю, как во вконтакте, не пользуюсь этой соц сеткой.
Но если нужно подсветить Cell'ки в таблице, то способов куча, и их реализация полностью ограничивается Вашей фантазией. 
 1. можно анимационно менять багграунд слоя во время прорисовки селки в методе

```
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
```

1. можно положить сверху слой и ему менять анимационно альфаканал.
2. можно сделать анимацию поддергивания.
3. Можно унаследоваться от UITableViewCell и вообще добавить свои методы анимации и реализовать пыщь пыщь из SKEmitterNode чтоб был солютик.
4. и т.д.